# I know that a maximal atlas isnt contained in another atlas.

Tags: differential-geometry

But here is a proposition that if A is a Ck atlas then its contained in a maximal atlas B.
and the proof is 
let B=Union C where C is an atlas Ck related with A . so B is a unique maximal atlas containing A.
But i cant recognize this proof . help plz

Comment: That looks like the scaffold of a decent proof to me. What is your issue with it? What do you mean you can't recognize it?

Comment: i cant recognize it because why did we had another atlas C and why if its Ck related with A then B is max and unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rewriting of the proof, using metaphors and visualisation rather than formal language.

For our manifold, there are *many* $C_k$-atlases. Some of them are $C_k$-related to $A$, and some are not. Take each and every one of those atlases, and if it turns out to be $C_k$-related to $A$, take all the charts in that atlas and throw it into a big pile (removing any duplicate charts we encounter along the way).

Once we've taken *all* such atlases (including $A$ itself), the pile now contains all possible charts that are $C_k$-related to $A$. This pile is therefore a $C_k$ atlas that is $C_k$-related to $A$, and there can't be any bigger atlas, because we have all possible compatible charts already. So this pile is a *maximal* $C_k$ atlas that contains $A$, and we call it $B$.